# Generalisation of Serret's integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Prove that $\;\displaystyle\int_{0}^{a} \frac{\ln(1+ax)}{1+x^2}dx = \tan^{-1}(a)\ln(\sqrt{1+a^2})$

For $a=1$, this is Serret's integral. So I thought the self similar substitution $x \rightarrow \frac{1+x}{1-x}$ would help but it didn't. 
I also applied integration by parts twice but it didn't help.